# How to fix the following warning for CRAN packages regarding packages which restrict the use of FOSS?

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I am creating an R package which depends on the following package `akima`, which is published on CRAN:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/akima/index.html

When I try to upload my R package to CRAN, there is a NOTE:

```
Package has a FOSS license but eventually depends on the following
package which restricts use:
  akima
```

I'm stumped how to fix this, or what this NOTE actually means.

Given this is a license with akima (which is on CRAN), is there something I could do to resolve this NOTE? My own package currently depends on GPL-3 as a license, which I believe is fine: https://cran.r-project.org/web/licenses/

Any help is appreciate here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overlooking the fact that `akima`, while on CRAN for mostly historical reasonas as it [goes back to CRAN releases as early as 1998 (!!)](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/akima/) is not actually free software -- see [its license](https://github.com/cran/akima/blob/master/LICENSE).

So the NOTE you got is on point: while *your* package may be free software, by depending on `akima` you are creating a conflicted bundle. So "don't do it" if you can.

And you can: the [interp](https://cran.r-project.org/package=interp) package was written for this purpose and says in its DESCRIPTION:

> It is intended to provide FOSS replacement functions for the ACM licensed akima::interp and tripack::tri.mesh functions.

There is more detail at the package. Hopefully is offers what you need.

Comment: I understand the situation now, thanks Dirk! This has been helpful! Thank you for sharing `interp`---I'll use this instead